# Conversion of int to char

Tags: c++, types, primitive-types

1)

```
#include<stdio.h>                    
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{

    char num = 'a';
    printf("%d", num);   Answer=97
    getch();
return 0;
}
```

1) how can we print no with char while using %d and data type as char

2)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{

    int num = 'a';
    printf("%c", num);  Answer=a
    getch();
return 0;`
```

2) how can we print char with int while using %c and data type as int

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
int a='b';
char c=a;
int d=c;
cout<<"value is "<< a ;        Answer=98
cout<<"\nChar is "<<c;         Answer=b
cout<<"\nint d is "<<d;        Answer=98
getch();
}
```

3) how can int be converted to char without explicit type casting. How is a that is int converts into char c without explicit type casting

Please explain the fundamentals.

Comment: Why `Java` tag here?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand the questions. Are you asking why `%d` interprets an argument as an integer while `%c` interprets it as a character? If so, the answer is simply that that's how `printf` and related functions are specified. As for `cout`, that works according to the type of its argument, so there's no alternative to a cast if you want it treated like a different type.

Answer (score 2):

to print char with int while using %c and data type as int

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num = 97;
    printf("%c", num);  //Answer=a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

printf is declared as a vadiadic function

`int printf(const char *format, ...);`

`char`s are converted to `int`s when passing them to variadic functions. `printf` converts it back to `char` internally.

see "Default Conversions" at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments